# Azure storage blob list with continuation token from specific point

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm working on a script to list the blobs in a container which has a ridiculous number of blobs (over 30 million!).

Anyway, I'm using the code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-3.8.0

Which appears to use a continuation token for every 10,000 files.

```
$MaxReturn = 10000
$ContainerName = "abc"
$Total = 0
$Token = $Null
do
 {
     $Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token
     $Total += $Blobs.Count
     if($Blobs.Length -le 0) { Break;}
     $Token = $Blobs[$blobs.Count -1].ContinuationToken;
 }
 While ($Token -ne $Null)
Echo "Total $Total blobs in container $ContainerName"
```

The problem is that this always ends up hanging or getting stuck and never completes.

It usually gets around half way and I have to restart it which kicks off the entire process all over again.

However, I already have the data from the first run, is there a way to get it to start from a specific value rather than from the start?

Lets say I already have the records I need for the first 3 million blobs. How do I tell it to start from 3 million instead of 0?

Or am I not understanding how the process works?

Comment: 2 Questions: 1) Are you storing the continuation token somewhere and 2) Is your data static i.e. blobs are not being added or deleted from your blob container?

Comment: I am not storing the continuation token, but I could. Are you suggesting I could use the last token (before it hangs) to continue? And the data in the container is static.

Comment: @amaru96a Since the data in the container is static, you can store the latest ContinuationToken. Then run the script with the ContinuationToken next time to get remaining blobs。

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try it out and report back.

Comment: Thanks Jim that seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a summary for the issue to let others know who has the similar issue.

> How do I tell it to start from 3 million instead of 0?

Since the data in the container is static, you can store the latest `ContinuationToken`. Then run the script with the `ContinuationToken` next time to get remaining blobs.

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-3.8.0).